# Assign multiple columns in pd.assign using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, assign

I am trying to take the difference between column pairs and create new columns with the column name and 'diff' using pd.assign and dictionary comprehension

A sample df looks like this:

```
df
    A    B    C    D    E    F
0   2    1    3    5    2    2
1   3    4    5    6    3    5
```

My mapping of which columns takes which difference looks like this:

```
column_mapping = {
'A': 'B',
'C': 'D',
'E': 'F'}
```

I have tried to create a kwargs dictionary comprehension for an assign method as such:

```
kwargs = {key+'_diff': lambda df: eval(f"(df['{key}'] - df['{value}']) / df['{key}']") for key, value in zip(column_mapping.keys(), column_mapping.values())}
```

I also tried

```
kwargs = {key+'_diff': lambda df: (df[key] - df[value]) / df[key]) for key, value in zip(column_mapping.keys(), column_mapping.values())}
```

This give a mapping of the lambda functions which I pass to .assign

```
df.assign(**kwargs)
```

This does work, however is produces all the diff columns with different names and the exact same numbers which are the difference of column E and F:

A sample df looks like this:

```
df
    A    B    C    D    E    F    a_diff   c_diff  e_diff
0   2    1    3    5    2    2    0        0       0 
1   3    4    5    6    3    5    -2       -2      -2
```

I think this should be possible and feel I am close but it believe it is iterating over all lambda functions instead of one. Please could someone help point what I am doing here.

If anything is unclear please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lets us fix your `assign` approach

```
df.assign(**{f'{k}_diff': df[k].sub(df[v]).div(df[k]) for k, v in column_mapping.items()})
```

Alternative approach with `assign`:

```
k, v =  map(list, zip(*column_mapping.items()))
df.assign(**((df[k] - df[v].values) / df[k]).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F    A_diff    C_diff    E_diff
0  2  1  3  5  2  2  0.500000 -0.666667  0.000000
1  3  4  5  6  3  5 -0.333333 -0.200000 -0.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop and assign the new column in the loop:

```py
for key, value in column_mapping.items():
    df[key+'_diff'] = (df[key] - df[value]) / df[key]
```